# Send HTML formated mail using PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I need to send emails with the content of a PHP page, but I am having trouble, as far as I could do is creating static format in HTML but if tomorrow the data has more rows the email will be incomplete,
I will share part of my mail.php

```
//The query

    $wipAgingQuery = $dbconnection->query("
        SELECT 
        CAST(datein AS DATE) AS [Date_In], 
        COUNT(lab) AS [Count_of_Jobs],
        ROUND(SUM(COUNT(lab)) OVER (ORDER BY datein DESC) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(lab)) OVER (),2) AS [Cumulative]
        FROM [DailyWIP].[dbo].[WIP_Daily_Load]
        WHERE location = 'USA' AND dateload BETWEEN CONCAT(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),' 11:30:00.000') AND CONCAT(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),' 14:00:00.000')
        GROUP BY datein ORDER BY datein DESC;");
        $jobInWip = $wipAgingQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

//Assign Query Result in Variable

    foreach ($jobInWip as $jobInWip) {
        $wipDateIn = $jobInWip -> Date_In;
        $wipCount = $jobInWip -> Count_of_Jobs;
        $wipCumulative = $jobInWip -> Lab_Cumulative;
        $totalJobCount = $totalJobCount + $wipCount; 
    }

//HTML inside the Mailer Body

    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12'>
            <h1>Current Day WIP: Aging</h1>
            <table class='table table-bordered'>
                <thead class='thead-dark'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date In</th>
                        <th>Count of Jobs</th>
                        <th>Lab Cumulative</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>$wipDateIn</td>
                            <td><p class='text-right'>$wipCount</p></td>
                            <td><p class='text-right'>$wipCumulative</td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Grand Total:</td>
                        <td><p class='text-right'>$totalJobCount</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the original wipdata.php page where I can manage that problem since the table is being created by a foreach depending on the results of the query, but I don't know how to do something similar in the mail.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Current Day WIP: Aging</h1>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Date In</th>
                    <th>Count of Jobs</th>
                    <th>Lab Cumulative</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($jobInWip as $jobInWip) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $jobInWip->Date_In ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo '<p class="text-right">'. number_format($jobInWip->Count_of_Jobs) .'</p>' ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo '<p class="text-right">'. number_format($jobInWip->Lab_Cumulative, 2) . ' %' ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $totalJobCount = $totalJobCount + $jobInWip->Count_of_Jobs;
                } ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo 'Grand Total: ' ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '<p class="text-right">'. number_format($totalJobCount).'</p>'; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh I just found a way around this, I am not sure if this is the best way to solve it but it worked.

```
foreach ($jobInWip as $jobInWip) {
    $wipDateIn = $jobInWip -> Date_In;
    $wipCount = $jobInWip -> Count_of_Jobs;
    $wipCumulative = $jobInWip -> Lab_Cumulative;
    $totalJobCount = $totalJobCount + $wipCount; 

$phpmailer-> Body .="<tr>
                        <td>$wipDateIn</td>
                        <td><p class='text-right'>$wipCount</p></td>
                        <td><p class='text-right'>$wipCumulative</td>
</tr>";}
```